# Approximation of continuous functions vanishing at a point with polynomials vanishing at the same point

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

Let $C[0, 1]$ denote the set of all real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$.
Consider the normed linear space
$$
X=\{f\in C[0,1]| f(\frac{1}{2})=0\}
$$
with the sup-norm
$$||f|| = \sup\{|f(t)| : t ∈ [0, 1]\}.$$
Show that the set
$$P=\{f\in X | f \text{ is a polynomial}\}$$
is dense in $X$.

I was trying to approach this problem using Weierstrass' approximation theorem but by doing so, for each $f\in X$, I can only find polynomials with roots in a neighborhood of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Let $p$ be a polynomial such that $|p(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon/2$ for all $x$. We can write $p(x)$ in the form $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}a_k(x-\frac 1 2)^{k}$. Let $q(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_k(x-\frac 1 2)^{k}$. $q$ is a polynomial vanishing at $\frac 1 2$.  Verify that $|q(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! For showing $|q(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, I proceeded as follows: $|a_{0}|=|p(\frac{1}{2})-f(\frac{1}{2})|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then used $|f(x)-q(x)|\leq |f(x)-p(x)|+|p(x)-q(x)|= |f(x)-p(x)|+|a_{0}|.$ Is this alright?

Comment: @outofspace0106 Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Every polynomial with root in a neighborhood of $\frac12$ can be approximated by a polynomial with root at $\frac12$. Just shift it a little bit in $x$ or $y$-direction.